# How to display the show hide option at the end of each column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here I want to display the show and hide function at the end of the of the table column, where it's showing at the top of the column now. It is using the first column of the table as the parent and displaying the show and hide at the first of the column.

**[Here the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vcqpo0t/2/)**

```
<div class="col-lg-12" style="width: 100%"

          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
<table class="table table-condensed"
style="border-collapse:collapse;">

<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Driver</th>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Cell Phone</th>
<th>Acct To</th>
<th>Container#</th>
<th>Ord Typ</th>
<th>Start Date</th>
<th>Start Time</th>
<th>Sched From</th>
<th>Sched To</th>
<th>Order Status</th>
</tr>
<tr data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target="#DADRVC" class="accordion-toggle">
<td><button
class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">
</span></button></td>
    <td> /%DADRVC%/ </td>
    <td> /%NMEFRS%/ </td>
    <td> /%PHNCEL%/ </td>
    <td> /%DAACCO%/ </td>
    <td> /%DACNT#%/ </td>
    <td> /%DAORDT%/ </td>
    <td> /%DASTRD%/ </td>
    <td> /%DASTRT%/ </td>
    <td> /%DASAFR%/ </td>
    <td> /%DASATO%/ </td>
    <td> /%DAORDS%/ </td>
</tr>
   <tr>
<td colspan="13" class="hiddenRow">
<div class="accordian-body collapse" 
id="DADRVC"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<div class="">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  <button type="button" 
class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span>SEND</button>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Mobile App</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Show Text</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Update App</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Thank You</button>
 <input type="text" class="col-sm-4"/>

</div></thead></table>
    </div>
        </td></tr>
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target="#DADRVC" class="accordion-toggle">
<td><button
class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">
</span></button></td>
    <td> /%DADRVC%/ </td>
    <td> /%NMEFRS%/ </td>
    <td> /%PHNCEL%/ </td>
    <td> /%DAACCO%/ </td>
    <td> /%DACNT#%/ </td>
    <td> /%DAORDT%/ </td>
    <td> /%DASTRD%/ </td>
    <td> /%DASTRT%/ </td>
    <td> /%DASAFR%/ </td>
    <td> /%DASATO%/ </td>
    <td> /%DAORDS%/ </td>
</tr>
   <tr>
<td colspan="13" class="hiddenRow">
<div class="accordian-body collapse" 
id="DADRVC"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<div class="">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  <button type="button" 
class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span>SEND</button>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Mobile App</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Show Text</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Update App</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Thank You</button>
 <input type="text" class="col-sm-4"/>

</div></thead></table>
    </div>
        </td></tr>
        <tr data-toggle="collapse" 
data-target="#DADRVC" class="accordion-toggle">
<td><button
class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">
</span></button></td>
    <td> /%DADRVC%/ </td>
    <td> /%NMEFRS%/ </td>
    <td> /%PHNCEL%/ </td>
    <td> /%DAACCO%/ </td>
    <td> /%DACNT#%/ </td>
    <td> /%DAORDT%/ </td>
    <td> /%DASTRD%/ </td>
    <td> /%DASTRT%/ </td>
    <td> /%DASAFR%/ </td>
    <td> /%DASATO%/ </td>
    <td> /%DAORDS%/ </td>
</tr>
   <tr>
<td colspan="13" class="hiddenRow">
<div class="accordian-body collapse" 
id="DADRVC"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<div class="">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  <button type="button" 
class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span>SEND</button>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Mobile App</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Show Text</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Update App</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Thank You</button>
 <input type="text" class="col-sm-4"/>

</div></thead></table>
    </div>
        </td></tr>
```

Here's the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the wording and comments, it looks like you mean "at the end of the **row**" - ie across, not the column (which would be down).  Please clarify within the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/7vcqpo0t/12/)**.

You've just to move the column to the end of the row like :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-12" style="width: 100%" <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">

      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Driver</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Cell Phone</th>
        <th>Acct To</th>
        <th>Container#</th>
        <th>Ord Typ</th>
        <th>Start Date</th>
        <th>Start Time</th>
        <th>Sched From</th>
        <th>Sched To</th>
        <th>Order Status</th>
      </tr>
      <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#DADRVC" class="accordion-toggle">
        <td> /%DADRVC%/ </td>
        <td> /%NMEFRS%/ </td>
        <td> /%PHNCEL%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAACCO%/ </td>
        <td> /%DACNT#%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAORDT%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASTRD%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASTRT%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASAFR%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASATO%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAORDS%/ </td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">
        </span></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="13" class="hiddenRow">
          <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="DADRVC"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <div class="">
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span>SEND</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Mobile App</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Show Text</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Update App</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Thank You</button>
                  <input type="text" class="col-sm-4" />

                </div>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#DADRVC1" class="accordion-toggle">
        <td> /%DADRVC%/ </td>
        <td> /%NMEFRS%/ </td>
        <td> /%PHNCEL%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAACCO%/ </td>
        <td> /%DACNT#%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAORDT%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASTRD%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASTRT%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASAFR%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASATO%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAORDS%/ </td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">
        </span></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="13" class="hiddenRow">
          <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="DADRVC1"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <div class="">
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span>SEND</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Mobile App</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Show Text</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Update App</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Thank You</button>
                  <input type="text" class="col-sm-4" />

                </div>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#DADRVC2" class="accordion-toggle">
        <td> /%DADRVC%/ </td>
        <td> /%NMEFRS%/ </td>
        <td> /%PHNCEL%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAACCO%/ </td>
        <td> /%DACNT#%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAORDT%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASTRD%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASTRT%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASAFR%/ </td>
        <td> /%DASATO%/ </td>
        <td> /%DAORDS%/ </td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">
        </span></button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="13" class="hiddenRow">
          <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="DADRVC2"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <div class="">
                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span>SEND</button> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Mobile App</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Show Text</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Update App</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn3d">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> Thank You</button>
                  <input type="text" class="col-sm-4" />

                </div>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's why you're putting everything inside **thead** tag, you need to put your show/hide function in the table's footer, using the tag **tfoot**. Like this:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>MyColumnHeader</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>MyContent</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td><button>show</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. I want to display the show and hide options at the end of the column.And I used the tfoot and it's not working

Comment: @Ajay_Venkatesh do you mean "at the end of **row**" (ie across) ?  At the end of the column is at the *bottom* (ie down) - where this answer will correctly place your buttons.